# Why do we georeference from the image to the shapefile (and not the other way around)?

Tags: raster, shapefile, geoprocessing, georeferencing

Why do we georeference going FROM the image, TO the shapefile (and not the other way around)?

Comment: it is definitely not clear what exactly are you asking. Usually you geoference an image and then digitize it because you are interested in the features depicted....that is the other way around? using features to georefence and image? we do that as well. depending on your needs

Answer (score 4):

If the shapefile has real-world coordinates and the image doesn't, we georeference the features shown in the image to matching features in the shapefile to pull the image into the same real-world coordinates.

On the other hand, if the image has real-world coordinates and the shape-file doesn't, then we can spatially adjust the features in the shapefile to matching features shown in the image to pull the shapefile features into the same real-world coordinates.

Comment: Thank you!  This was a homework question and I found it to be confusing as well.

Comment: If this has answered your question then please consider marking it as the answer